# First error: unexpected token: 'NOT'

Tags: apex, soql

Here is the query I am trying to execute. Not sure what might be the problem

```
query = 'select Id,name,username,email from User where Username__c= true AND NOT(Username LIKE %portal%)'
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008kAQIAY might help. Just a quick google search. I didn't try it though

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, UserName, Email FROM User WHERE Username__c = true AND (NOT Username LIKE \'%portal%\')';
database.query(query);
```

`NOT` should be inside the parenthesis and your keyword should be a String.

Only change is in this where clause:

```
AND (NOT Username LIKE \'%portal%\')
```

> Note: To avoid Injection, use [escapeSingleQuotes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method.

Comment: The parenthesis actually don't matter for a static query (haven't checked it dynamically though). You also fixed something else important! :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if I include NOT outside like `NOT (Username LIKE \'%portal%\')`, it throws error as- `System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'NOT'`.

Comment: I meant you can just remove them. If you include them, then their placement matters.

Comment: Yup you're right as usual! :) I was just referring to the example here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem with your dynamic query is that you have not wrapped your search term in quotes:

**Invalid**

```
query = '...NOT Username LIKE %portal%';
// compiled query clause: NOT Username LIKE %portal%
```

**Valid**

```
query = '...NOT Username LIKE \'%portal%\''
// compiled query clause: NOT Username LIKE '%portal%'
```

If you use parentheses, they must wrap the entire clause (`(NOT Username Like '...')`), but they are not necessary, and the clause works just as well if you remove them (`NOT Username LIKE '...'`).